# proxy error requesting https

Tags: c#, https, proxy, httpwebrequest

I am using this little piece of code to access remote Uri's :

```
Uri uri = "http://www.myurl.com";
WebRequest wreq = WebRequest.Create(uri);
((HttpWebRequest)wreq).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.75 Safari/537.1";
wreq.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
```

This is working perfectly for all "http" Uri. However, when switching to the following type of Uri's (https), i am getting a proxy error 407 requesting authentification (log of the Exception tells that credentials are bad). Do you have any idea of how i could handle this ?

```
Uri uri = "https://www.myurl.com";
WebRequest wreq = WebRequest.Create(uri);
((HttpWebRequest)wreq).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.75 Safari/537.1";
wreq.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
```

Best regards,

Al_th

Comment: You are using your system wide settings for proxy. Check the IE proxy settings or internet settings from the control panel (assuming you are using Windows) and see if you can access https://www.myurl.com site from IE. May be your https proxy setting is bad?

Comment: From the control panel,  i have a proxy IP / port defined, and the checkbox "use the same proxy server for all protocols". 
I can access to https://www.myurl.com without any problem from IE, and the same for chrome (which was not configured in any way by the system admin because i "downloaded" it after getting on the computer, and didn't need any installation so it bypassed the installation security policy of the place i work at. I assume the credentials used are stored on the computer, but i thought that DefaultWebProxy use the same configuration as chrome/IE :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private string GetPageSource(string url)
{
    string htmlSource = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        System.Net.WebProxy myProxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("Proxy IP", 8080);
        using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            client.Proxy = myProxy;
            client.Proxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            htmlSource = client.DownloadString(url);
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        // log any exceptions
    }
    return htmlSource;
}
```

Comment: Which username/password should i use ? My session login information ? 
Should'nt that be included in DefaultWebProxy ?

Comment: Do you get any login box popin up when browsing to https://yoururl.com if so, then you should add those credentials as login and pass, at least if you know them

Comment: Try to uncomment // the lines starting with client.Proxy and try your https url again and see what result you get

Comment: I'll be able to test it out tomorrow, i do not have access to that computer right now. However i do not have any login box poping up when browsing https://www.myurl.com either with IE nor whith Chrome.

Comment: Try the code tomorrow and let me know, how it goes, if it doesnt ima help you out more

Comment: I'm sorry because yesterday was national day in france, i did forget that. And i'm not at work until next week :> I keep you informed as soon as i can apply your solution !

Comment: I finally get back to work, and tried what you gave me (with some modifications) and it worked perfectly.

For later use of this post if someone ever wanted to know, i replaced the new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user","pass") with CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredential. 

Thanks a lot !